# Content Length in Golang

Tags: http, go

I couldn't find anything helpful online on this one.

I am writing an REST API, and I want to log the size of the body of the request in bytes for metrics. Go net/http API does not provide that directly. http.Request does have Content-Length field, but that field can be empty or the client might send false data.

Is there a way to get that in the middlware level? The bruteforce method would be to read the full body and check the size. But if I do that in the middleware, the handler will not have access to the body because it would have been read and closed.

Comment: It's still, as you say, "bruteforce", but you CAN use a middleware to read it, check the size, then replace it back into the `Request.Body` using a new  `io.ReadCloser` because that is all the `Body` is. https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#Request

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Why do you want a middle in here?
The simple way is `b, err = io.Copy(anyWriterOrMultiwriter, r.Body)`
`b` is total content length of request when `err == nil`
Use request body as you want. Also `b, err = io.Copy(ioutil.Discard, r.Body)`

Answer (score 5):

You could write a custom `ReadCloser` that proxies an existing one and counts bytes as it goes. Something like:

```
type LengthReader struct {
    Source io.ReadCloser
    Length int
}

func (r *LengthReader) Read(b []byte) (int, error) {
    n, err := r.Source.Read(b)
    r.Length += n
    return n, err
}

func (r *LengthReader) Close() error {
    var buf [32]byte
    var n int
    var err error
    for err == nil {
        n, err = r.Source.Read(buf[:])
        r.Length += n
    }
    closeerr := r.Source.Close()
    if err != nil && err != io.EOF {
        return err
    }
    return closeerr
}
```

This will count bytes as you read them from the stream, and when closed it will consume and count all remaining unread bytes first. After you're finished with the stream, you can then access the length.

Comment: Brilliant! Almost makes it seem odd that this isn't a builtin thing already. And here I was trying to figure out how to avoid copies using middleware.

Comment: This is a smart way of doing it indeed. The only issue (and i failed to mention this in the question) is that i would not know the size of the request when it comes, rather after it is read.

Comment: @Husain Fair. Though it's impossible in the general case to get the size of the request without reading it first, and with the other answer you're simply reading the entire request up front and storing it to be reread later.

Answer (score 3):

## Option 1

Use [TeeReader](https://golang.org/pkg/io/#TeeReader) and this is scalable. It splits reader into two and one of them calculates the size using allocated memory. Also, in the first case

```
  maxmem := 4096
  var buf bytes.Buffer
  // comment this line out if you want to disable gathering metrics
  resp.Body = io.TeeReader(resp.Body, &buf) 

  readsize := func(r io.Reader) int {
    bytes := make([]byte, maxmem)
    var size int
      for {
        read, err := r.Read(bytes)
        if err == io.EOF {
        break
      }
      size += read
    }
    return size
  }

  log.Printf("Size is %d", readsize(&buf))
```

## Option 2 unscalable way (original answer)

You can just read the body, calculate the size, then unmarshal into struct, so that it becomes:

```
    b, _ := ioutil.ReadAll(r.Body)

    size := len(b) // can be nil so check err in your app
    
    if err := json.Unmarshal(b, &input); err != nil {
        s.BadReq(w, errors.New("error reading body"))
        return
    }
```